# SPRING BOOT: Cannot delete Entity that have @manytomany relationships

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to delete a Film entity that has a many to many relationship with "User" entity and "artist" entity. It also has a ManytoOne with "genre" entity and "pays"(it means country in English). And finally a OneToMany with "listNoteComment"(basically means review)[Artist Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO1bw.png) [Film Model, as you can see I've tried many cascade types here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sExrd.png) [User Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFVn4.png)

I've tried to delete it by clearing the list of user and artist first with this function [deleteMapping function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5VWh.png) But my main problem his the error I get, in fact I have a error 500 with no explanation so i really don't know what to try and correct next[error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Rvv.png) Any help will be much appreciated...

Also I'm very sorry for my poor english, it's not my first language

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error is not related to the many to many relationship but it's related on the List/HashMap you're using to delete it. Try to use a for and not a foreach. The problem is caused by the secure loop, while itering you cannot modify a list (deleting or adding an element).

Comment: Thanks you very much, indeed the problem came from the foreach loop, it's fixed now!